# How to change text of wxComboBox based on it's selected item

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

How to change the value of a `wxComboBox` when user selects an item from its own drop down list? I have added `EVT_COMBOBOX(ID_WXCOMBODATETIME, CNFrm::WxComboDateTimeSelected)` to my `EVENT_TABLE`.

```
void CNFrm::WxComboDateTimeSelected(wxCommandEvent& event )
{   
    WxComboDateTime->SetValue   ( "ljlk" );
}
```

trying `SetValue` in the function just empties the control, it doesn't set it.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the table value.
I use connect, I find it more elegant and less intrusive.
When you build your combo box, you need to plug it this way:

```
handler->Connect(
  the_combobox->GetId(),
  wxEVT_COMMAND_COMBOBOX_SELECTED, 
  (wxObjectEventFunction) &MyHandler::onSelected);
```

And then later:

```
void MyHandler::onSelected(wxEvent& the_event)
{
}
```

Note that `MyHandler` must be a `wxEvtHandler`, but if you have and object inheriting from `wxComboBox` or `wxPanel`, `wxWindow`, it's fine since they are all `wxEvtHandler`.

Also there are three different events, I'm not sure which one is the most suited for you need: `wxEVT_COMMAND_COMBOBOX_SELECTED`, `wxEVT_COMMAND_TEXT_UPDATED`, `wxEVT_COMMAND_TEXT_ENTER`